# C#: Adding polymorphism to generated partial classes/properties

Tags: c#, polymorphism

How can one add (non-trivial) polymorphic implementations to generated classes in C#?

For example, say my (non-modifiable) generator spits out a hundred classes that look like this:

```
public partial class Table1 {
    public int StatusID { get; set; }
    // other properties, etc.
}
```

And I want to add this property to all of them:

```
public enum Statuses {
    Unknown,
    Good,
    Error
}

public Statuses Status {
    get { return (Statuses)StatusID; }
    set { StatusID = (int)value; }
}
```

How can I do that? I can't use a base class because that would required `overrides` on the generated properties. I can't use an interface because I want the implementation, not just the definition.

Comment: What's the use of that? Because it won't really allow flexibility between those classes, so this new property is not very special... And why can't your generator just add it to every class it generates?

Comment: @Yotam, I don't have access to the generator, so I can't change the generated classes. This is a simplistic example I could get along without, but the general case of adding a property/method to multiple generated classes would be obviously useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're describing is a [mixin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixin), and it's not available in C# without IL weaving (compile time) or a dynamic proxy (runtime).

**Compile time mixin**

Essentially your generated classes will live in a special assembly, and the property will be added at the time the compiler runs. This special property will not be visible from within the assembly itself, but will be visible to consumers/users of the assembly. There is [Cilador](https://github.com/rileywhite/Cilador) and [Mixins.Fody](https://bitbucket.org/skwasiborski/mixins.fody/wiki/Home) - both free, but both unmaintained/discontinued. There's also [PostSharp](https://www.postsharp.net/) which is commercial, but provides a free version which may be able to obtain this as well.

**Dynamic proxy**

Here the goal will be a little different - substitute the runtime type with a dynamically generated type using a proxy. In the framework, [`RealProxy`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.remoting.proxies.realproxy(v=vs.110).aspx) can be used, in dotnet core [`DispatchProxy`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Reflection.DispatchProxy) can be used. In both cases, this will be less-nice to use than the compile time mixin, and I think it would be best to show you rather than explain:

```
Table1 table = ...

// this creates a proxy (dynamic type) which derives from Table1. This can be used to wrap ANY type with a status property
Table1 proxy = ProxyGenerator.WrapConcreteWithStatusProxy(table);

// the IStatusObject interface and implementation is being provided by the proxy, and is only accessible via a cast.
IStatusObject tableStatus = (IStatusObject)proxy;
tableStatus.Status = Statuses.Good;
```

If you're familiar with emitting IL, you can achieve a high level of customisation using this approach.

**Summary:**

I have had less success with compile time mixins - the free oss discontinued libs wont work out of the box, and the commercial free options are limited although they work very well. In theory, compile time mixins are the much better option because they give you increased performance, intellisense and avoid runtime casting.

That said, the dynamic proxy is sure to work and be more reliable. I've used dynamic proxies in this, or similar ways, in dozens of projects - and in a lot of them i generate the dynamic types myself by emitting IL. This also gives you the added benefit of being able to wrap any type with the status property, even if you didn't know about the base type at compile time. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, that wasn't the answer I was hoping for, but it solves the problem. I realized that for methods I could define an interface and then add an extension method, but extension properties aren't in C# yet.

Comment: Cilador is my project. It's mostly focused on adding code rather than modifying it, but I believe you could use the tooling to make the modifications you want. It is out of date, but that's mostly because I haven't kept up with Fody versions. The direct CIL manipulation tooling/code cloning should work.

Comment: You can simulate extended properties using extension methods and a static dictionary.